# How do i use switch statement inside a method such that the method can return a char value which is acquired by the switch statement inside it?

Tags: java, methods, switch-statement, return

This method is suppose to calculate the average of the scores obtained and return the grade accordingly.
How do i pass the grade from switch() to the calculate() so that it could return the right grade?

```
public char calculate(){

    int count=0;
    int total = 0;
     for (int x: testScores){
             total = total + x;
             count++;
     }  

     int grade = total/count;

        switch(grade){
                case (1): if (grade>=90) return 'O';
                break;
                case(2): if (grade>=80 && grade<90) return 'E';
                break;
                case (3): if (grade>=70 && grade<80) return 'A';
                break;
                case (4): if (grade>=55 && grade<70) return 'P';
                break;
                case (5): if (grade>=40 && grade<55) return 'D';
                break;
                case (6): if (grade<40) return 'E';
                break;
            }
            return //what should i return here??

    }
```

i know how to do it without switch(), but i think it could be done this way as well. 
plz tell me what am i missing?

Comment: If you match the `case (1)` when switching over `grade`, then `grade == 1`, so it isn't `>= 90`. I think you are getting a bit confused.

Comment: Simple return some dummy value there - doesn't matter what - just to silence the compiler. (Compiler doesn't detect, that the line is unreachable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning your question:

- the last return is not needed, just end `switch` with `default` clause
  and return default value there.
- there is no need to use `break` stetements, since you are using
  `return` on each case

Also, if you are limiting yourself to only use `switch`, then this is one simpler way to achieve your goal:

```
char calculate(int[] scores) {
  double averageScore = Arrays.stream(scores).average().getAsDouble();
  int nearestMultipleOfFive = 5 * ((int) averageScore / 5);
  switch (nearestMultipleOfFive) {
    case 100:
    case 95: 
    case 90: return 'O';
    case 85:
    case 80: return 'E';
    case 75: 
    case 70: return 'A';
    case 65: 
    case 60:
    case 55: return 'P';
    case 50: 
    case 45:
    case 40: return 'D';
    default: return 'E';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you covered all cases with the switch statement, and you return immediately for each of them, you shouldn't do anything there, you will never reach that part of the code. 
In the code that you currently have the `break` statement is also useless because it will never be reached in any of the cases because once again it is anticipated by a return statement.

You can modify your code a bit if you want to return the value once in the end by storing the outcome of the switch case in a previously defined variable and returning that one at the end.

Comment: Well it will  not compile without some dummy return value. As the compiler doesn't detect that all possible values already covered(It will complain about a missing return!). So the OP needs just st. to silence the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch your last `case` to `default` instead of an actual value, it would eliminate the need to return anything after the `switch` statement.

More broadly speaking, your `if` statements inside each `case` are suspect. How can `grade == 1` and `grade >= 90`? The only one that could possibly work is case 6 since 6 is also < 40. You're trying to use 1-6 as some sort of logical label, but in reality the JVM is comparing the value of `grade` to those numbers to decide what case to execute.

I think there is an easier way to express this logic. It looks like `grade` will be their numeric grade (i.e. between 0 an 100 though in theory it could also be negative), so I would ditch the `switch` statement and just use if/else:

```
  if (grade >= 90) {
     return 'O';
  } else if (grade >= 80 && grade < 90) {
     return 'E';
  } else if (grade >= 70 && grade < 80) {
     return 'A';
  } else if (grade >= 55 && grade < 70) {
     return 'P';
  } else if (grade >= 40 && grade < 55) {
     return 'D';
  } else {
     return 'E';
  }
```

Notice the last statement is just `else` without any condition. This makes it work like the `default` case in a `switch` statement: it will catch any value that didn't meet the other criteria.

Answer (score 0):

In your switch you jump to the different parts checking if `grade` is 1, 2, 3, etc. But then you compare it to values in the range of 0 to 100? That can never work out.

But you don't need a switch at all, you can just use a series of `if` statements

```
public char calculate(){

  int count=0;
  int total = 0;
  for (int x: testScores){
    total = total + x;
    count++;
  }  

  int grade = total/count; //what if count is 0?

  if (grade>=90) return 'O';
  if (grade>=80) return 'E';
  if (grade>=70) return 'A';
  if (grade>=55) return 'P';
  if (grade>=40) return 'D';
  return 'E';
}
```

And make sure to cover the case when `count` is 0, I have not done it here, because I don't know what should be the result then.